# ggplot draw specific boundaries for each group?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi Suppose I have a dataframe like this.

```
id     gene    value      upper    lower
AE5    ATM 4.046142  0.5440875 5.941381
AE5    ATR 3.463361  1.5046214 4.867110
AE5  BRCA1 4.228049 -0.7397759 5.791135
AE5  CDK12 4.488001  1.6029831 6.106177
AE5 CDKN1A 4.837943  2.1936042 9.880194
AE6    ATM 3.629939  0.5440875 5.941381
AE6    ATR 3.121015  1.5046214 4.867110
AE6  BRCA1 4.368070 -0.7397759 5.791135
AE6  CDK12 4.759688  1.6029831 6.106177
AE6 CDKN1A 5.757290  2.1936042 9.880194
```

I can plot this with ggplot

```
ggplot(final , aes(y=gene, x=value, col=id)) +
  geom_point(size=5)
```

and it gets me this plot here.
[image]

However what I want in addition is to have boundary lines for each group based on the upper and lower column of the dataframe.  So for example ATM will have small vertical lines crossing on .54 and 5.9.  This way I can visualize better where each of the samples land.
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `geom_errorbarh` from the `ggstance` package. To have a single range line regardless of `id` (since the range is the same for both levels of `id`), move the colour aesthetic into `geom_point` so it will apply only to the points and not the error bars. We also set the data in `geom_errorbarh` to select only one `id` to avoid having the same error bars plotted on top of each other multiple times.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstance)

ggplot(final , aes(y=gene, x=value)) +
  geom_errorbarh(data=final[final$id=="AE5",], aes(xmin=lower, xmax=upper),
                 width=0.2, colour="grey50") +
  geom_point(size=5, aes(col=id)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

To get just vertical lines, you can do two calls to `geom_point` using `"|"` as the point marker (although I think it's easier to read the graph with the horizontal lines to guide the eyes).

```
ggplot(final , aes(y=gene, x=value)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=upper), shape="|", size=5) +
  geom_point(aes(x=lower), shape="|", size=5) +
  geom_point(size=5, aes(col=id)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks that is neat.  Any way to get rid of the horizontal lines but retain the verticals ? I tried setting alpha but it effects both.